# Pass A.Class into public B(Class<? extends C>) when A implements C

Tags: java, reflection

I have a function B that has this declaration:

```
public void B(Class<? extends C> clazz);
```

I have a class A and a class C that look like this:

```
public interface C {}
public class A implements C{}
```

I would like to do this:

```
B(A.class);
```

However Java is wanting me do to this (and then complains about unchecked casts)

```
B( (Class<? extends C>)A.class );
```

How do I indicate to Java that this is all type-safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me:

```
interface C {}
class A implements C {}

public class Test {

    private static void foo(Class<? extends C> clazz) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        foo(A.class);
    }
}
```

Perhaps you could post a short but *complete* example of what's failing?

Comment: Sorry about that, I saw 'extends' and I assumed C was a class, turns out it's an interface. Java needs to stop overloading keywords and make up it's mind about whether to threat interfaces like super-classes

Comment: @Huckle: I've edited my sample code for that, and it still works. Again, please show a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: OK, I see what's happening here. I didn't have an `import C` in A.java. Eclipse didn't gaff at the lack of a import until I made a change to the line. And then in the class I called B in it decided to manifest the error as indicating that A didn't implement C.